# Belongs to / subset problem in topology

Tags: general-topology

I'm studying topology and I came across with the following problem which is a bit confusing to me:

> The set $\Large\tau$ is called a discrete topology if it is the
>   collection of all subsets of non-empty set $X$.
>
> If $X=\{a,b,c,d,e,f\}$ and $\Large\tau$ is the discrete topology on
>   $X$, which of the following statements are true:
>
> (a) $X\in \Large\tau\;\;\;$   (b) $\{X\}\in\Large\tau\;\;\;$ (c)
>   $\{\varnothing\}\in\Large\tau\;\;\;$ (d)
>   $\varnothing\in\Large\tau\;\;\;$
>
> (e) $\varnothing\in X\;\;\;$   (f) $\{\varnothing\}\in X\;\;\;$ (g)
>   $\{a\}\in\Large\tau\;\;\;$ (h) $a\in\Large\tau\;\;\;$
>
> (i) $\varnothing\subseteq X\;\;\;$   (j) $\{a\}\in X\;\;\;$ (k)
>   $\{\varnothing\}\subseteq X\;\;\;$ (l) $a\in X\;\;\;$
>
> (m) $X\subseteq \Large\tau\;\;\;$   (n)
>   $\{a\}\subseteq\Large\tau\;\;\;$ (o) $\{X\}\subseteq\Large\tau\;\;\;$
>   (p) $a\subseteq\Large\tau\;\;\;$
>
> Hint: Precisely six of the above are true.

If I were to do this task I would say that (a), (d), (g), (i), (l), (n) were true. I wonder if I got it right or wrong?

The problem can be found [here](http://www.topologywithouttears.net/topbook.pdf) Page 26 task 3

Comment: I think you're right.

Comment: Since they didn't tell you what are $a,b,c,d,e$ and $f$ *a lot* of the supposedly false statements can be true (for example, if $a=\varnothing$ and $b=\{\varnothing\}$, then e,f,j,k,n and p are true).

Comment: @AsafKaragila And if they asked "Which of the following statements are necessarily true?", then that would be OK?

Comment: In my opinion this is a very odd and somewhat worthless question...where did you find it?

Comment: @Arthur: It would be better, yes. You'd have to fix the hint as well. The point I'm trying to make is that mathematics is about attention to details as much as it is about the big picture.

Comment: Thank you everybody for your answers :) @AnthonyPeter I updated my post where to find this question.

Comment: Note that (a) and (o) are equivalent statements, and so are (n) and (h), but in your list only (a) and (n) appear.

Comment: Thank you @MatthiasKlupsch =) Yes I was also a bit confused about that because I was given that precisely six are true.

Comment: The correct answer is (a), (d), (g), (i), (l), (o).

Comment: Thank you @Crostul appreciate your help =)

Comment: (n) is false, because $a \notin \mathcal{T}$. And being a subset means that every element left is an element right...

Comment: Thank you @HennoBrandsma =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(a) $X \in \mathcal{T}$  true, all subsets of $X$ are in the discrete topology on $X$ (and $X$ is of course in *any* topology on $X$ by the first axiom of topology as well).

(b) $\{X\} \in \mathcal{T}$: $\{X\}$ is not a subset of $X$, as $X \notin X$, so this cannot be true. (assuming the axiom of foundation)

(c) $\{\emptyset\}$ is also not a subset of $X$ (because otherwise $\emptyset \in X$ which is false, assuming, as I suppose we must assume here, that all of $a$ to $f$ are different from $\emptyset$ (a priori, $\emptyset$ *can* be an element of a set, but as $X$ is enumerated as $\{a,\ldots,f\}$, we assume this is not the case here (the question is somewhat badly formulated, IMHO).

(d) $\emptyset$ is a member of any topology on $X$, so true.

(e) $\emptyset \in X$ we assume is false (see (c)).

(f) $\{\emptyset\} \in X$ we likewise assume to be false (see (c), we assume $a$ to $f$ are "unrelated" elements, not the empty set, or this set, e.g.)

(g) $\{a\} \in \mathcal{T}$ is true, because $\{a\} \subset X$ (because $a \in X$, by enumeration) and all subsets of $X$ are in $\mathcal{T}$.

(h) $a \in \mathcal{T}$ is false, as $a$ is not a subset of $X$ (we assume; a priori $a = \{b\}$ could hold, and then $a$ would be a subset of $X$!; this is part of the bad formulation criticism).

(i) $\emptyset \subseteq \mathcal{T}$ is true: all elements of $\emptyset$ are in $\mathcal{T}$, this is an empty statement as there *are* no elements. Or equivalently, $\emptyset \subseteq A$ is true whatever $A$ is.

(j) $\{a\} \in X$ is false (we assume, see before, as $b$ *could* equal $\{a\}$ for all we know... ).

(k)  $\{\emptyset\} \subseteq \mathcal{T}$ is true, as $\emptyset \in \mathcal{T}$ (inclusion: every element left is an element right..)

(l) $a \in X$, true by inspection.

(m) $X \subseteq \mathcal{T}$, false, as $a \in X$ but not $a \in \mathcal{T}$, see (h).

(n) $\{a\} \subseteq \mathcal{T}$ is false, as $a \in \{a\}$ but not $a \in \mathcal{T}$, see (h) again.

(o) $\{X\} \subseteq \mathcal{T}$ is true, as the only element left, $X$, is indeed an element of $\mathcal{T}$, see (a).

(p) $a \subseteq \mathcal{T}$ I call false (it's not known what the elements of $a$ are, if $a = \{b\}$ happened to be true, then it would hold, so really we cannot say based on what's given).

Under the given assumptions, indeed 6 are true.

Comment: Thank you for your answer =)